# Create Directory linked to external server (website) via ftp

Tags: server, directory, ftp

I'm totally new to Ubuntu and linux in general, so please forgive me if this has been asked before.

I'm a web developer and have moved to ubuntu. I was wondering if it was possible to have a directory linked direct to my websites server (via ftp) rather than using a ftp client and uploading/downloading through that. (Pretty much exactly how the dropbox desktop app works)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried in nautilus "connect to server?" enter the address as ftp://my.ftp.server/ and should work...

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I'm new to ubuntu. That sounds exactly what I need, but would I do that on a specific folder? Sorry, could you explain in laymans terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "connect to server" option in `nautilus`, the file manager of Ubuntu (at least in the standard Unity and Gnome versions). It is called "Files": (the screenshot is from a Gnome version of Ubuntu):

[image: Files]

Launch it and choose connect to server. You will have a dialog, enter the ftp direction in the form:

```
 ftp://ftp.server.com/
```

Substitute the name or IP of your server, be careful of the syntax (you have to start with `ftp://` with the two forward slashes). In the example I am using a public ftp server for the TeX repository:

[image: add a server]

Click connect and you will be asked for the credential (in my case I choose anonymous, you probably will need to give user and password):

[image: credentials]

You can choose to give the credential for just this session or forever, you choose here.

Et voilà, you can use your "share"  as if it where a local folder.

[image: tex-archive]

You can disconnect to the server by using the small triangle on the side of the name.

To reach the volume with a shell, you normally search under `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`  ($UID is your User Identification Number, you can see it in the shell with `echo $UID`).

Note that read-only ftp shares can behave strangely when doing complex operations (for example, trying to create a file I had an Input/output error instead of a permission denied.